# C++ Lookup of i changed for ISO

Tags: c++, function, iso

I have the following code for a dictionary.

```
void Dictionary::translate(char out_s[], const char s[])
{

for (int i=0;i<numEntries;i++)
{
   if (strcmp(englishWord[i], s)==0)
       break;
}
if (i<numEntries)
strcpy(out_s, elvishWord[i]);
```

which gives me the error `name lookup of i changed for iso` and mentions that the code will be accepted if i use `-fpermissive`. If i try and initialize the variable outside the for loop it generates a whole load of errors.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Move the declaration of i to appear above the for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not "for iso" (perhaps **read the entire error message...**), but for ISO C++. The problem is that the scope of the `i` variable is only the `for` loop (since its definition is inside the initialization of the loop). Since it seems you want to use it outside the loop, declare it like so:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < foo; i++) {
    // ...
}

do_safe_stuff_with(i); // valid
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do e.g.

```
for (int i=0;i<numEntries;i++)
```

then the variable `i` is local to the loop only, you can't really use it outside the loop.

If you want to use `i` outside the loop, then you need to declare it outside the loop:

```
int i;
for (i=0;i<numEntries;i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

`i` is declared in the `for` loop condition clause. it is not visible at the `if` clause after `for` loop.

try:

```
int i = 0;
for (;i<numEntries;i++)
{
   if (strcmp(englishWord[i], s)==0)
       break;
}
if (i<numEntries)
```